# Js bind "своими руками"

Tags: javascript

В целом нужно было создать свой bind, который будет иметь тот же функционал, что и встроенный bind (нельзя использовать call, apply). Вот как это сделал я:

```js
Function.prototype._bind = function(ctx, ...args) {
  ctx.__temp__ = this;
  return (function() {
    return ctx.__temp__(...args);
  });
}

let obj = {
  name: 'ban'
};

function getname() {
  return this.name;
}

let fnc = getname._bind(obj);
console.log(fnc());
```

Создание нового свойства у контекста - вообще не вариант, так вот вопрос можно ли сделать это лучше (без нового свойства контекста).

Comment: Напутано с параметрами - не работает (.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Создание нового свойства у контекста - вообще не вариант, так вот вопрос можно ли сделать это лучше (без нового свойства контекста).
>
> можно ли сделать это без нового свойства контекста

Да, можно - используйте `Symbol()` вместо ключа.

```js
let obj = {
 a: 'A', b: 'B'
}

q: {
 let key = Symbol()
 obj[key] = 'q 1'
}
q: {
 let key = Symbol()
 obj[key] = 'q 2'
}

q: {
 obj[Symbol()] = 'q 3'
 obj[Symbol()] = 'q 4'
}

let objKeys = Object.keys(obj)
let objSymbols = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(obj)
let objSymbolsValues = objSymbols.map(key => obj[key])


/**
 obj              {"a":"A","b":"B"}
 objKeys          ["a","b"]
 objSymbols       массив символом, смотри в консоле
 objSymbolsValues ["q 1","q 2","q 3","q 4"]
 */
document.body.innerHTML = `
<pre>
obj              ${JSON.stringify(obj)}
objKeys          ${JSON.stringify(objKeys)}
objSymbols       массив символом, смотри в консоле
objSymbolsValues ${JSON.stringify(objSymbolsValues)}
</pre>
`
```

[MDN Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)

> Символ (анг. Symbol) — это уникальный и неизменяемый тип данных, который может быть использован как идентификатор для свойств объектов.